# AngularJS : How to get returned value from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angularjs-http

I am very much new in AngularJS and I have the following problem:

View:

```
<div>
    <form role="form" name="loginForm" class="form-horizontal login-form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <p class="login-form-msg">Welcome : {{user.username}}</p>
            <label for="inputUserName" class="col-sm-2 control-label login-form-label">Base</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter base" class="form-control" required ng-model="user.code">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUserName" class="col-sm-2 control-label login-form-label">Username</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" class="form-control" required ng-model="user.username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label login-form-label">Password</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" required ng-model="user.password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10 login-form-button">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-disabled="loginForm.$invalid" ng-click="login(user)">Sign in</button>
            </div>
            <p class="login-form-msg">{{msgtxt}}</p>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Main js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller:'loginCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/welcome', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/welcome.html',
        controller:'loginCtrl'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}]);
```

I have the following factory:

```
myApp.factory('getURLService', function ($http, config) {
    return {
        getURL: function (user,scope) {
            $http.get(config.backend + "/Device/GetURLbyCode", {
                params: { code: user.code }
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                var url = '';
                if (data.status == 'succ') {
                    url = data.Result;
                }
                else {
                    scope.msgtxt = data.msg;
                }
                return url;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I need to use the returned value from this factory in other factories.

For example in my login factory:

```
myApp.factory('loginService', function ($http, $location, config) {
    return {
        login: function (user,url,scope) {

            $http.get(url + "/Device/Register", {
                params: { userName: user.username, password: user.password }
            })
            .success(function (data) {
                if (data.status == 'succ') {
                    $location.path('/welcome');
                }
                else {
                    scope.msgtxt = data.msg;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

This is my controller:

```
myApp.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, getURLService, loginService) {
    $scope.msgtxt = '';

    $scope.login = function (user) {
        loginService.login(user,url,$scope); //call login service
    }
});
```

What do I need to do in my controller to actually return the url and then send it to the login service or any other service (or even controller) in the future?

Thanks in advance for your time and suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For returning data from the function you should return promise object which `$http.get` already returns it.

Additional thing which I wanted to point out is, passing $scope to the service disobey the rule of singleton, as you are creating a service which is dependent of the controller scope. Service should only accept the parameter and return the result by processing it, nothing else.

**Code**

```
return {
    getURL: function (user,scope) {
        return $http.get(config.backend + "/Device/GetURLbyCode", {
            params: { code: user.code }
        })
        .then(function (res) {
            var data = res.data;
            var url = '';
            if (data.status == 'succ') {
                url = data.Result;
            }
            else {
                scope.msgtxt = data.msg;
            }
            return url;
        });
    }
}
```

**LoginService**

```
myApp.factory('loginService', function ($http, $location, config) {
    return {
        login: function (user,url) {

            return $http.get(url + "/Device/Register", {
                params: { userName: user.username, password: user.password }
            })
            .then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                if (data.status == 'succ') {
                    $location.path('/welcome');
                    return;
                }
                return data.msg;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
getURLService.getURL(user).then(function(url){
     //assuming you already having value of user available here
     loginService.login(user,url).then(function(message){ //call login service
         if(message)
            $scope.msgtxt = message;
     }); 
});
```

Comment: First of all thank you for you quick response. I get an error that code is undefined. How can I pass it to getURL service? Sorry for my novice questions.

Comment: @wolf basically you need to pass user object to getUrl method

Comment: @Wolf you should have user object populated..I assumed that while writing an answer..

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the user object is what I insert in the input fields. I added my view to the question if that makes more sense.